# How to avoid infinite loop in saga?

Tags: redux, axios, saga

I cant understand why the code above runs infinite loop. My actions are different. Could u   please take a look?

```
import { call, put, takeLatest ,delay} from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { saveFetchedDevices,fetchDevicesRequest } from './devicesRedux'
import axios from "axios"

 const getDevices= () => {
     return axios.get("http://localhost:3131/devices")
}


function* fetchDevicesHandler(action) {
   try {
      const response = yield call(getDevices);
      yield delay(3000);
      yield put(saveFetchedDevices(response.data));
      
   } catch (e) {
       console.log(e)
   }
}

function* mySaga() {
  yield takeLatest(fetchDevicesRequest,fetchDevicesHandler);
}

export default mySaga;
```

fetchDevicesRequest is dispatched from button. Then loop starts

delay is just to slow down infinite loop

Comment: Have you checked that the action types of `fetchDevicesRequest` and `fetchDevicesHandler` are not the same?

Comment: They are different. I think u mean saveFetchedDevices and fetchDevicesRequest. fetchDevicesHandler i didnt set type becouse i dont now how :)

Comment: How do you create the actions?

Comment: i put code below

Comment: Edit the question and move the code into. It's not an answer.

Comment: And you don't need the delay

Answer (score 0):

this is my redux file

```
const createActionName = function(name) {
    return `app/devices/${name}`
}

const ADD_DEVICE = createActionName("ADD_DEVICE");
const UPDATE_DEVICE = createActionName("UPDATE_DEVICE");
const REMOVE_DEVICE = createActionName("REMOVE_DEVICE"); 
const SAVE_FETCHED_DEVICES = createActionName("SAVE_FETCHED_DEVICES"); 
const FETCH_DEVICES_REQUEST= createActionName("FETCH_DEVICES_REQUEST"); 

//action creators
export const addDevice = payload => ({ type: ADD_DEVICE, payload })
export const updateDevice = payload => ({ type: UPDATE_DEVICE, payload })
export const removeDevice = payload => ({ type: REMOVE_DEVICE, payload })
export const saveFetchedDevices = payload => ({ type: SAVE_FETCHED_DEVICES, payload })
export const fetchDevicesRequest = payload => ({ type: FETCH_DEVICES_REQUEST })

//selectors
export const getAllDevices = state => state.devices.data;

const reducer = function(statePart = [], action = {}) {
    
    switch(action.type) {
        case SAVE_FETCHED_DEVICES:
            return { data:  action.payload  }
        case ADD_DEVICE:
            return { ...statePart, data: [ ...statePart.data, action.payload ] }
        case UPDATE_DEVICE:
            return { ...statePart, data: [ ...statePart.data.map((device)=>device.id===action.payload.id?action.payload:device)] }
        case REMOVE_DEVICE:
            return { ...statePart, data: [ ...statePart.data.filter((device)=>device.id!==action.payload.id)] }
                default:
            return statePart
    }
}
           
export default reducer
```

Comment: How to put this code in previous comment? when i put in between triple code quotes it says that it is to much code